# Accordion menu has a jumpy transition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

I have an issue where where the accordion menu looks fine on my codepen, but when I actually implement the accordion menu on my site it has a jumpy transition. You can check out the codepen below:

https://codepen.io/tiffany-koval/pen/OJRVKGp

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: "Avenir Next Demi Bold";
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: auto;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.line-break {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.faq h1 {
   font-family: "Avenir Next Medium";
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq h2 {
  font-family: "Avenir Next Medium";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.faq {
  margin-top: 100px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
    .faq {
  margin-top: 40px !important;
}
}
/** =======================
 * Accordion
 ===========================*/

 .accordion {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin: 30px auto -5px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
 }

.accordion .link {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 18px 15px 18px 15px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li:last-child .link {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.accordion li i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
    right: 12px;
    left: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.accordion li.open .link {
    color: #000;
}
.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion li.default .submenu {display: block;}
/**
 * Submenu
 -----------------------------*/
 .submenu {
    display: none;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
 }

 .submenu p {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
 }

 .submenu p {
    display: block;
  font-family: "Avenir Next";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
 }

 .submenu p:hover {
    background: #fbfbfb;
    color: #000;
 }
/**
 * More FAQs
 -----------------------------*/
.accordion + .more-faqs {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  background: none !important;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  margin-left: 115px;
  font-size: 10px !important;
}

#more-faqs {
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: "Avenir Next Medium";
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
        this.el = el || {};
        this.multiple = multiple || false;


        var link = this.el.find('.link');

        link.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple},this.dropdown)
    }

    Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
        var $el = e.data.el;
            $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();

        $next.slideToggle();
        $this.parent().toggleClass('open');
        
        if(!e.data.multiple){
            $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
        }
    
    }

    var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

I keep thinking it has something to do with the padding or the height of the accordion menu itself, but playing around with the code results in no change. How could I make the accordion menu on my site look more like my codepen? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On the store page, you have an additional margin of `1em 0` on the `<p>` element (rule `.content-asset p` from `style.min.css`). This vertical margin seems to disappear and re-appear at a different moment than the rest of the `<p>`, even though the margin seems to have no visible effect. Setting this margin to `0` removes the jumpiness, as far as my tests indicate. You might have to override it (define anew, or even enforce it with `!important`), in case you have no control over `style.min.css`.

I think the root cause of the jumpiness is that you have a "target" margin on the element, but not a real "source" margin in the same direction for the transition to base itself on. A transition needs clearly defined start and end points for every transitioned property.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a web page where I had two accordions, where clicking on one accordion moved the other one up and down. Once I put on the background colors I saw that blank spaces in the elements were over lapping.

Try and throw distinctive background colors on the elements to see if any of the elements are overlapping each other. If the width and height of elements are not set in CSS or HTML sometimes blank space in elements will overlap and may cause things to move around un-intentionally on the web page. Also I did not have top or bottom margins on the specific accordions, due to float usage. (However if use the position: fixed; style in your CSS then set the margins to get it where you want it, should not move when you click on the accordion).